# Android Phonegap Application restart if all data come from server-side

Tags: android, cordova

In my phonegap application  everything to come from server-side (e.g HTML/JS/CSS also phonegap-1.0.0.js) because of in my application include PHP Script. and load web-url from my phonegap application For example:

package com.test;

import com.phonegap.*;

public class TestActivity extends DroidGap {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setBooleanProperty("loadInWebView", true);
    super.loadUrl("http://somewebsite/index.html");
    //ORIGINAL--> super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

}

Now problem with this application is when screen orientation change or camera functionality use from our application restart application.

please help me and reply answer on this post

Thanks,
Nilesh

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the orientation of your Activity in the manifest inside the activity tag:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name="SomeActivity"/>
```

This will probably fix the camera issue too.

The other thing: if you don't use PhoneGap functionality (no native access, no hooks, no PhoneGap java scripting on client side) then you'll probably be better off with your Activity that has a WebView as it's content view. This way your application will be lighter and you will have more control over the content loading (you could save the last visited URL in SharedPreferences, and load it in onResume(), you clould implement user, session and cookie management etc.)